# Getting SQL Error: ORA-00904: "STATUS": invalid identifier while using join in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I am getting below error when I am firing below `update` query with `Join`. Please help me to fix this out.

> SQL Error: ORA-00904: "STATUS": invalid identifier
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Query Is:

```
UPDATE (
    SELECT
        a.COLUMN_35,
        a.network_nni 
    FROM 
        Table_1 a
    JOIN Table_2 b 
    ON a.COLUMN_35 = b.COLUMN_35
    AND a.network_id = b.network_id
    WHERE b.COLUMN_35 IS NOT NULL
    AND a.status = 'Status_1'
)
SET status = 'Status_2';
```

Please check this and suggest at the earliest.

Comment: is it not neccessary to mention alias name while setting the value like `set a.status='Status_2'` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to update a.status column for that you need to select that column in the select statement

Try below query

```
 update 
   (select a.status as Stat
   from Table_1 a
   JOIN  Table_2 b ON
   a.COLUMN_35=b.COLUMN_35
   and a.network_id= b.network_id
   where b.COLUMN_35 is not null
  and a.status='Status_1') b
 set b.stat = 'Status_2';
```

Comment: status is a column name. and when I do it with [], I am getting thid error,SQL Error: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification
01747. 00000 -  "invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification"

Comment: @Msn you need to update a.status column for that you need to select that column in the select statement